# angular cli include/exclude scripts in index.html depending on the environment

Tags: javascript, cordova, webpack, angular-cli

I have angular 2 application (angular cli is used). And I want to build web and mobile (cordova) version for the app.

So I want to use `ng build -e prod` to build for production and `ng build -e cordova --output-path mobile/www --base-href ./` to build for cordova project.

I want to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` if environment is cordova and exclude facebook web api script, and vise versa if environment is production

Comment: What solution did you go with?

Comment: Does it have to be in it's own script tag? If not you can use require('path/to/file.js) based on env

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution.

Based on the answer by Ionaru in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451)

In main.ts:

```
if (environment.production) {

  document.write(
    `
      <script type="text/javascript">
         // JS code here
      </script>
    `
  );

  enableProdMode();
}
```

I believe this to be the simplest way to conditionally embed code as once was done directly on index.html